# form.save(commit = False) not returning instance id

Tags: django

`model 1`

```
class Products(models.Model):
    product_category = models.ForeignKey(ProductCategory)
    product_sub_category =  models.ForeignKey(ProductCategory)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
   is_active = models.BooleanField(default = True)
   and so on...
```

`model 2`

```
class ProductImages(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey( Products )
    product_image = models.FileField(_('Attachment'), upload_to='attachments')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default = True)
```

`CreateView`

```
class ProductCreate(CreateView):
    model = Products
    template_name = "products/product_add.html"
    fields = ['product_category', 'product_sub_category', 'product_name', 'size', 'color', 'price', 'price_info', 'description_1', 'description_2', 'about_product', 'features', 'specification']
    success_url = "products/product-list"  

    def form_valid(self, form):
        product_form = form.save(commit = False)
        # **expecting product_form.id to be non None**
        if 'product_images' in self.request.FILES:
            for img in self.request.FILES.getlist('product_images'):
                 ProductImages(product = product_form, product_image = img).save()

       super(ProductCreate, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Problem statement :
    form.save( commit = False ) returning Product instance but product id is None. Is it illegal to expect object id as object is not yet saved to db?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The id is allocated by the database, and since `commut=False` explicitly means "don't send to the db", it won't have an id.

Comment: How do I Save product Images before Product?

Comment: Just remove the commit=False.

Comment: `super(ProductCreate, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)`  won't save the form again?

Comment: So it worked by removing `commit = False` and call to super. Had to return `HttpResponse`